If an attorney were to submit your provisional application, what account will it be submitted under?
I just created an account with the USPTO.gov website.
When the attorney submits my provisional, what account will they use?

Why aren’t you asking the attorney?

I want to know what is done in the industry in general. That way I can compare against what my attorney does to see if there is a consensus?

What do mean by account ? You might mean customer number or you might mean the deposit account that holds some funds with the USPTO.

I meant the account that you register with the USPTO.gov website.

A patent practitioner uses their account with the USPTO to log in and when submitting an application uses their or their firm’s customer number and also normally references a deposit account for the USPTO to take any required fees from if not otherwise covered.
Their signature includes their registration number.

If it is submitted under the attorney's account, can the client log in to view the progress?

Just people under the customer number and possibly their staff.

what is a customer number?

If you don’t trust your patent attorney it will be a difficult and needlessly expensive process.

You might ask that as a new question, maybe after you google it.
